# Store unicode characters in golang

Tags: string, go, unicode

I'm creating a data structure for storing single unicode characters which I can then compare.

Two Questions:

1. What data types do I use?

   `type ds struct {
       char Char // What should Char be so that I can safely compare two ds?
   }`
2. I need a way to compare the first character of any two unicode strings. Is there a simple way to do that? Basically, how do I retrieve the first unicode character of a string?

Comment: Now I have given complete code demonstrating this.

Answer (score 2):

Like this: `type Char rune`.

Pay attention to "compare", that is a complicated thing with Unicode. While code points (`rune`s) are easy to compare numerically (U+0020 == U+0020; U+1234 < U+2345) this might or might not be what you want given case, combining characters and what else Unicode offers.

Comment: How do I then access the first rune of a unicode string?

Comment: unicode/utf8.DecodeRune[InString]: https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRune and DecodeRuneInString

Answer (score 1):

2. To compare utf8 strings, you need to check their runevalue. Runevalue is int32 value of utf8 character. Use standard package "unicode/utf8". Pass "string[0:]" to get the first character

   ```
       test := "春节"
       runeValue, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(test[0:])
       fmt.Println(runeValue,width)
       fmt.Printf("%#U %d", runeValue, runeValue)
   ```

Now you can compare runeValue of two strings's first character using == operator

1. Also you need to store string in string if you want to store whole character.

   ```
   type ds struct {
       char string // What should Char be so that I can safely compare two ds?
   }
   ```

Complete code demonstrating this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

type ds struct {
    char string // What should Char be so that I can safely compare two ds?
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    ds1 := ds{"春节"}
    ds2 := ds{"春节"}

    runeValue1, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(ds1.char[0:])
    runeValue2, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(ds2.char[0:])

    fmt.Printf("%#U %#U", runeValue1, runeValue2)

    if runeValue1 == runeValue2 {
        fmt.Println("\nFirst Char Same")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("\nDifferent")
    }
}
```

[Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FrNocJPHV8)

Answer (score 0):

From Volkers, answer, we can just use rune to compare.

1. `type Char rune`
2. to get the first unicode character we can simply do `[]rune(str)[0]`

Comment: You don't need to do type Char rune. Unless you are doing []Char(str)[0]